# Inductor on collector of RF transistor

Tags: rf

I posted my current circuit mounted on PCB with printed antenna approximately 120mm long.
Transmission is done in OOK.
Dout data varies between 0v and 5v levels.
Transmission frequency of 433Mhz according to crystal XTAL1.
I would like to understand the function of L1 to scale it as efficiently as possible, and with the greatest possible reach.
The entire circuit is assembled in SMT.

Can anyone explain to me the function of the L1 inductor in the RF transmitter circuit in the image below, and the reactions of the circuit to different values ​​of L1?

[image: RF circuit]

Credits: Personal collection

Comment: The output stage looks like a class-E amplifier, which may be a useful search term.

Answer (score 1):

> *Can anyone explain to me the function of the L1 inductor in the RF
> transmitter circuit*

The overall circuit is a rare example of a common-base Colpitts oscillator that is resonator/crystal controlled and modulate-able. More commonly you see the [common-collector version](http://www.seekic.com/circuit_diagram/Signal_Processing/Oscillator_Circuit/COLPITTS_1_to_20_MHz_CRYSTAL_OSCILLATOR.html) such as in this example: -

[image]

But, that is a fixed-value oscillator so, to "pull" the crystal (modulate the frequency a little), they have opted for the common-base version. In that type of circuit an inductor **is needed** and, an advantage that the inductor brings is that the p-p voltage output waveform can be larger for the same supply DC voltage. But it still forms part of the resonant circuit.

> *the reactions of the circuit to different values ​​of L1*

L1 can be changed in value but, not very much. If I had the time (unfortunately not today) I'd simulate it and see. You have to bear in mind that the crystal has a very small frequency range that it can be tuned/pulled so, any significant value change to L1 would likely prevent it from oscillating.

Comment: I redid the question, with a real image to make the most of the content from the cooperators.

Answer (score 0):

That arrangement is similar to a grounded-base oscillator of this form (left):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXFMOW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For the Colpitts oscillator shown below, frequency is determined primarily by inductance of L1 combined with capacitance of C1. Transistor's \$C_{CE}\$ adds some capacitance, while C2 and \$C_{BE}\$ tend to lower oscillator frequency.

At right, a high-Q resonator is connected from base to ground, where the series-resonant frequency of XTAL1 is a low-impedance. Thus the base is effectively grounded at one frequency.
But positive feedback required for oscillation (rightmost circuit) is still derived from transistor collector-to-emitter via C3 (3pf), and still depends on LC parallel resonance. If collector impedance is too low, it won't oscillate.

Antenna directly connected to collector adds some reactance. Antenna reactance depends on its length:

- Antenna length shorter than 1/4 wavelength adds capacitive reactance.
- Antenna length between 1/4 wavelength to 1/2 wavelength adds inductive reactance.
- Antenna straight wire of about 0.33m would be 1/2 wavelength. This length is a high impedance (self-resonant) that adds very little reactance.

A collector inductor of 150nH has 409 ohm inductive reactance at 434MHz.
Circuit capacitance (2.2pf), \$C_{CB}\$, antenna reactance should combine to be roughly equal to reactance of that collector inductor.

One might use antenna length to optimize radiated power. With some lengths, oscillation can cease. One might try antenna lengths between 1/4 and 1/2 wavelength. Adding a few 1/4 wavelength wires (open-ended) to GND might help - keep them away from the radiating antenna.

I've shown 2N3904 transistor in these circuits, but at 433 MHz, it has too little gain to oscillate with any confidence. Choose a transistor with gain-bandwidth at least a few GHz.

Inductors in these circuits are very often air-wound, with no apparent means of changing their value. They might be mashed or bent until oscillations occur reliably. Sometimes a variable capacitor adjusts collector's resonant frequency.

Optimizing collector inductor will also involve changing length of a directly-connected antenna wire. One might even try replacing the inductor with a wire loop of length between 1/4 and 1/2 wavelength.

---

BTW: C1 should be populated with a small capacitor. Perhaps 0.5nf - 1nf. Otherwise, connection to the DC supply adds significant inductance that seriously alters circuit operation.

Comment: I redid the question, with a real image to make the most of the content from the cooperators.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of L1 is to provide a high impedance at RF, and a low impedance at DC. This is to increase gain. This can be done either by using the inductor as a resonant circuit or as a choke.

A resonant circuit will give a high impedance over a narrow bandwidth. In this case changing the inductance without changing the frequency will most likely degrade performance. Changing the frequency without changing the inductance (and some other components) will most likely degrade performance.

As a choke, an inductor can provide a high impedance over a broad bandwidth. The value wouldn't be as critical as a resonant circuit but changing it could still degrade performance.

Telling whether it's a choke or resonant depends on the value, a choke will have a higher value that's not going to be resonant with the amount of capacitance in the circuit. A 27 nH inductor would be resonant with around 5 pF at 433 MHz.

Comment: I redid the question, with a real image to make the most of the content from the cooperators.

Comment: Most of the places I've seen inductors (chokes) like that are to prevent the RF from migrating onto the (in this case) the +12 V rail.  Once that happens it can corrupt other RF channels that are powered by that same 12 V rail.

Comment: @SteveSh Nah, that’s not what this one does, this is more like the collector resistor in audio frequency CE amp. You will sometimes see a choke between this inductor and B+, that one would be for keeping RF out of the power rails.

Comment: @DeusJihyo Can you give more details on the subject?

Comment: @TiagoMendonça Is there something specific that you need to know? What are you trying to do with the circuit?

Comment: @DeusJihyo, I want to transmit dados in OOK, and I would like to understand the function of L1 to choose the best value, where I can get the best performance from the transmitter.

Comment: @TiagoMendonça The optimum inductor value will depend on several things, the transistor type, the capacitors, the load, and at 433 MHz layout will make a difference. RF design is akin to voodoo at times, I can't just give you  a simple formula to calculate the best value. You started with an existing design that used 27nH, that would probably be a good starting point. Have you tried simulating the circuit?

Comment: That example with 27nH wasn't real. I chose this value of 150nH by chance through a worthless scheme. Can you recommend free software for simulating RF circuits?

Comment: @TiagoMendonça You might try LTspice, QUCS or Micro-Cap. I think Micro-Cap may be a bit better for RF than LTspice, I see it has the BFR93A transistor model included.